# Maintain a List of Daily Maxima Using a Trigger

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm developing an application retrieving data from a small number of sensors in an interval of 10 seconds. Those values are stored in a single-table sqlite database.

One use case of this application is to print the daily maxima of each sensor which is read.

I don't like the idea of issueing a `MAX...GROUP BY day` like query every time I want to retrieve those values, so I thought of maintaining a second table containing thos daily maxima.

1. Is this the appropriate way of performing such a task?
2. I tried writing such a trigger, but it didn't work. I'm somehow missing the ability to do the comparison among new value, and value for the current hour already in the db (which might be no value, if a new hour just started)

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER update_maxima AFTER  INSERT ON tick
   BEGIN
       INSERT OR REPLACE INTO maxima (time, device_id, lW) 
       VALUES (
           strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', 'now') , 
           new.device_id,
           (select case when new.lW > (select lW from maxima where device_id = new.device_id AND time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', 'now'))
               then 
                   new.lW
               else 
                   (select lW from maxima where device_id = new.device_id AND time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', 'now'))
               end
           )
       );
   END
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You say you like the trigger better; it's hard to argue with that. ;-)

   If you want a technical reason: the trigger is more efficient if you do the maximum-per-day query more often than some new value is inserted.
2. The `select lW...` subquery return a `NULL` value if there is no matching value in the table.
   Any comparison with `NULL` will result in `NULL`, which makes the `CASE` return the `ELSE` value, which is `NULL`.
   You have to wrap the subquery into an [IFNULL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) call.
3. You can simplify your `CASE` into a `MAX` with two parameters:

   ```
   ... VALUES (
           strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', 'now'),
           new.device_id,
           max(new.lW,
               ifnull((SELECT lW
                       FROM maxima
                       WHERE device_id = new.device_id
                         AND time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', 'now')
                      ),
                      0)
              )
       )
   ```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, I'll test it and accept your answer